# is Python available in any Ubuntu installation?

Tags: installation, python, repository, synaptic

Quite simply: is python already provided in any of the latest installations Ubuntu or does it have to be installed explicitly by the user?

Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Python is an [essential package](https://askubuntu.com/questions/79665/keep-only-essential-packages) because much of Ubuntu is based on Python. Ubuntu will not run without it.